# Updating scope attributes binded with promises

Tags: angularjs

The name property of the scope is not updated with the value returned from the $timeout.
$timeout returns a promise resolved by the value returned from the function provided to it. And I read the view bindings accept promises. But it doesn't work for me.

```js
      angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope,$timeout){


          $scope.name = $timeout(function () {
              return "World";
          }, 3000);
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Have no idea why you are trying to do this (probably influenced by $resource implementation?), however you could try something [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFXXFt?p=preview). I dont think view bindings accepts promises anymore, that was a long back story i guess.

Comment: @PSL so I was reading an old article then!?

Comment: Guess so. It was removed from 1.2 rc. `$parse and templates in general will no longer automatically unwrap promises. This feature has been deprecated and if absolutely needed, it can be reenabled during transitional period via $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true) api. feature added in rc.2 that unwraps return values from functions if the values are promises (if promise unwrapping is enabled - see previous point), was reverted due to breaking a popular usage pattern.`

Comment: According to this you would need to set it in the config [Like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWKizA?p=preview)

Comment: @PSL Perfect. You should have answered this question instead of a comment.  Thank you PSL

Comment: @PSL yes, you should! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you are using the [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) function is wrong, do this instead:

```
      $timeout(function () {
          $scope.name = "World";
      }, 3000);
```

The `$timeout` function retrieves a promise, not the `return` value of your inner function.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.name = "World";
}, 3000);
```